# Sublime text 2: Is there a way to store .workspace in a separate folder?

Tags: sublimetext, sublimetext2

For every project that is created with Sublime Text 2 a pair of files are created in the same directory the user decides to store the project file. Eg. for the 'ExampleSite' project Sublime creates 2 files named ExampleSite.project and ExampleSite.workspace

Is it possible to store the .workspace file in a separate directory?

Comment: __[Project Manager](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Project%20Manager)__ offers improved project navigation & allows custom directories to be specified.

You might be able to create a `Projects` directory & a `Workspaces` directory, and then add both of them to the Project Manager settings file.

Answer (score 0):

Project - Save Progect As ...

and delete old files from Project folder

Comment: This doesn't seem to work. When I do that, the .workspace files are created again in that new location.

Answer (score -1):

Yes.
.sublime-project has the "path".
The sublime-workspace is a little more complicated.